# Jquery is it possible to refresh page if download start?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have an application which the user choose the `checkbox`, 
press button `download` and download the data based on checked box, 
the problem is if i am not checking any `checkbox`, it will show `error` message in `div` alert.
and when i check and click download, download run well, but the error message is still in the page.
how to detect if download start, automatically page refresh, or how to solve it more easily?

my download code :

```
  public function downloadFile($name)
  { 
    $storagePath = "/opt/tmp/";

    // check filename for allowed chars (do not allow ../ to avoid security issue: downloading arbitrary files)

    if (!is_file("$storagePath/$name")) {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('The file does not exists.');
    }
    return Yii::$app->response->sendFile("$storagePath/$name", $name);
  }
```

how i can make detect download start and refresh it using jquery?

Comment: show us your javascript and html code. you do not need to reload/refresh your page, just like you add error message on you div, you can remove/hide it too with javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Hide the Error message as soon as you click on Checkbox.
something Like that
$("#id").hide();

Here id is the Id of the error message div

Answer (score 1):

You can detect download start when client click download link.

Before send request!

Something like this:

```
$('#download-link').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.location.reload();
    }, 500);
    return true;
});
```